# How to update edittext from IntentService class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

I'm making a chat app and using intent service for sending messages to firebase database even after activity is destroyed. When the uploading is successful i want to clear text in Edittext in the IntentService class but don't know how to do it.

> Acivity class code

```
Intent sendmsgService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SendMessageService.class);
        sendmsgService.putExtra("msg",message);
        sendmsgService.putExtra("time",time);
        sendmsgService.putExtra("cuser",current_user);
        sendmsgService.putExtra("otheruser",otherusername);
        startService(sendmsgService);
```

> IntentService class code

```
    public class SendMessageService extends IntentService {
DatabaseReference msgDatabase , mDatabase;
String current_user,otherusername,message,time;

public SendMessageService() {
    super("SendMessageService");
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    msgDatabase = mDatabase.child("messages").child(current_user).child(otherusername);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    assert intent!=null;
    message = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
    time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    current_user = intent.getStringExtra("cuser");
    otherusername = intent.getStringExtra("otheruser");
    DatabaseReference push_database =  msgDatabase.push();
    String msg_push = push_database.getKey();
    DatabaseReference d = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String cuser = current_user+"/"+otherusername+"/";
    String ouser = otherusername+"/"+current_user+"/";
    Map<String,Object> chatitems = new HashMap<>();
    chatitems.put("seen",false);
    chatitems.put("msg",message);
    chatitems.put("from",current_user);
    Map<String,Object> msgitemmap = new HashMap<>();
    chatitems.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    msgitemmap.put("servertime",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    msgitemmap.put("time",time);
    msgitemmap.put("msg",message);
    msgitemmap.put("from",current_user);
    msgitemmap.put("to",otherusername);
    msgitemmap.put("seen",false);
    msgitemmap.put("key",msg_push);
    Map<String,Object> chatmap = new HashMap<>();
    chatmap.put("chatlist/"+cuser,chatitems);
    chatmap.put("chatlist/"+ouser,chatitems);
    chatmap.put("messages/"+cuser+msg_push,msgitemmap);
    chatmap.put("messages/"+ouser+msg_push,msgitemmap);
    d.updateChildren(chatmap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

               //Here i want to clear the edittext 

        }
    });
}}
```

> If any other solution please suggest.

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent service runs on **background** thread not on **main(UI)** thread but we can use the Handler mechanism to send/update data to activity.
To send data to activity you need to declare handler in your activity like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle reply = msg.getData();
                            // do whatever with the bundle here
            }
};
```

in the intent service class pass data in this way:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Messenger messenger = (Messenger) bundle.get("messenger");
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.setData(data); //put the data here
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.i("error", "error");
        }
    }
```

**Most Important invoke the intent service from activity to pass handler to it:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentService1.class);
        intent.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(handler));
        startService(intent);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This one too worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use `Broadcast Reciever` Declare this in your activity class

```
BroadcastReceiver broadCastNewMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do your stuff here
            edittext.setText("");

        }
    };
```

Now in `onCreate()` register this

```
registerReceiver(this.broadCastNewMessage, new IntentFilter("uploading_done"));
```

And in `onDestroy()`

```
unregisterReceiver(broadCastNewMessage);
```

Now Call this method from the **service** class where u want to update the activity

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("uploading_done"));
```

Comment: did this help you ?

Comment: yes it did help a lot. Your solution is very simple and perfect for what i wanted. Thank you for your help.